# Write a string begin 0 by app google script (google sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I read a array of string from a google sheet then i write the first 4 char in a google sheet. The first char of string is 0. The output is a number not a string.

I read from sheet

0560_AAA,
0561_BBB,
0565_CCC,
7670_DDD

I want write in sheet

0560,
0561,
0565,
7670

the code below write

560,
561,
565,
7670

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var DATI = ss.getSheetByName("DATI");
var DATI_A=ss.getSheetByName("DATI_A");

var M_DATI=DATI.getRange(1,1,4,1).getValues();
var M_DATI_W=DATI_A.getRange(1,1,4,1).getValues();


for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
    M_DATI_W[i]=M_DATI[i].substring(0,4)
}

DATI_A.getRange(1,1,4,1).setValues(M_DATI_W);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve `0560_AAA, 0561_BBB, 0565_CCC, 7670_DDD` from cells "A1:A4" of "DATI" sheet, want to convert the value to `0560, 0561, 0565, 7670`. And, you want to put the converted values to the cells "A1:A4" of "DATI_A" sheet.

#### Modification points:

- The value retrieved with `getValues()` is 2 dimensional array. In your script, `M_DATI[i]` of `M_DATI[i].substring(0,4)` is an array. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue.
- And, when `0560` is put to the cell, the value is changed to `560` as a number. If you want to put it as a value of `0560`, it is required to set the format.
- In your script, the values are retrieved from both sheets. In this case, you can retrieve the values from the source sheet.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var DATI = ss.getSheetByName("DATI");
  var DATI_A = ss.getSheetByName("DATI_A");
  var M_DATI = DATI.getRange(1, 1, 4, 1).getValues();
  var values = [];
  for (i = 0; i < M_DATI.length; i++) {
    values.push([M_DATI[i][0].substring(0, 4)]);
  }
  DATI_A.getRange(1, 1, values.length).setNumberFormat("@").setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the above goal is obtained.
- When `DATI_A.getRange(1, 1, values.length).setNumberFormat("@").setValues(values)` is modified to `DATI_A.getRange(1, 1, values.length).setValues(values)`, `0560` is put into a cell as `560`.
- I think that from your sample value, `values.push([M_DATI[i][0].substring(0, 4)])` might be able to be replaced with `values.push([M_DATI[i][0].split("_")[0]])`.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setNumberFormat(numberFormat)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)